# Joomla 3.3.1 - Can't edit and create new menus in Menu Manager

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla3.3

I would like to add two new menus to my website, but when I create, or even edit a menu and click Save, Save & Close and Save & New nothing happens.
With Firebug I get

```
ReferenceError: Hash is not defined
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is this a new/fresh install?  If so you might want to download and unpack a new archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a thread here where people have the same problem, and it suggests just clearing your browser's cache fixes it.

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=844728&p=3171823#p3171823

That would make sense if you have recently upgraded it and Joomla have updated a javascript file from the previous version.

If not, might be worth seeing if it works in other browsers, to see if it is a Joomla or a similar browser issue.

Failing that, re-install the latest version to make sure you haven't overridden any core files.

Comment: from the linked forum thread, "I'd suggest that you clear your cache.
In Firefox it's; Tools | Options | Advanced | Network | Cached Web Content - Clear Now " - message by mkhpd